# SQL-Snowflake - How to count the days between dates in 2 or more rows wtih WHERE condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

| COUNTRY | STORE_ID | ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DE | 990003975 | 2023-01-24 |
| FR | 990004963 | 2023-04-11 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-15 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-10 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-07 |
| JP | 990005210 | 2023-01-08 |

I have data presented like the table above.
I need a way to add a column that shows me the difference in days between the dates of the same STORE_ID, ordering them in DESC order, I need the difference between the top date, and the previous one. Repeat for other dates of the same STORE_ID if they exist.
If there are no more dates, or just 1, put a 0.
So, for this example, I need to get something like this:

| COUNTRY | STORE_ID | ORDER_DATE | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE | 990003975 | 2023-01-24 | 0 |
| FR | 990004963 | 2023-04-11 | 0 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-15 | 5 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-10 | 3 |
| FR | 990005204 | 2023-06-07 | 0 |
| JP | 990005210 | 2023-01-08 | 0 |

I tried something like this that I saw in another question, but not sure why it's not working for me (I get nulls in the new column)

```
SELECT  country,
        store_id,
        order_date,
        NextDate,
        DATEDIFF(day, order_date, NextDate)
FROM    (   SELECT  country,
                    store_id,
                    order_date,
                    (   SELECT  MIN(order_date) 
                        FROM    main T2
                        WHERE   T2.store_id = T1.store_id
                        AND     T2.country > T1.country
                        AND     T2.order_date > T1.order_date
                    ) AS NextDate
            FROM    main T1
        ) AS T
order by 2,3
```

Comment: You most likely want to use LAG to get the prior date

Comment: Agreed LAG/LEAD would be cleaner. But what you are doing now seems perfectly fine too. NextDate will just return null for records that are already the latest for the store. So simply coalesce NextDate to order_date. Or coalesce the final calculation to 0. Or maybe as easy as T2.order_date > T1.order_date to T2.order_date >= T1.order_date

Comment: not just cleaner, but massively faster, the cost of the order-by of the LEAD/LAG verse the JOIN it orders of magnitude on a large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I swapped to [LEAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead) over LAG, and your desciption of time descending, changes the relationship of what the "other wanted value" is:

```
with data(country, store_id, order_date) as (
    select * from values
        ('DE', 990003975, '2023-01-24'::date),
        ('FR', 990004963, '2023-04-11'::date),
        ('FR', 990005204, '2023-06-15'::date),
        ('FR', 990005204, '2023-06-10'::date),
        ('FR', 990005204, '2023-06-07'::date),
        ('JP', 990005210, '2023-01-08'::date)
)
select 
    *
    ,lead(order_date,1,order_date) over (partition by store_id order by order_date desc) as lead_order_date
    ,datediff('days', lead_order_date, order_date) as days
from data
order by 2,3 desc;
```

gives:

[image]

which can be compressed like:

```
select 
    *
    ,datediff(
        'days', 
        lead(order_date,1,order_date) over (partition by store_id order by order_date desc), 
        order_date
    ) as days
from data
order by 2,3 desc;
```

giving a cleaner answer:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Didn't know those functions existed. Thanks!

Comment: This is why I answer questions, boot strapping others knowledge makes the worlds SQL run faster.